# Executing php from another file

Tags: php, templates

i have 1 template-file, which is included into main file.

**some.template**:

```
...
<?php echo '!'; ?>
...
```

in main file i read file into 1 variable and display it. Of course, php script doesn't run there. How can i do that, what i want?

Thanks

Comment: What modifications do you have to do? Show them for us, and there may be a way to write a template that you don't have to modify and eval (which is extremely insecure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `include` to read and process the file. If you need to post-process the result (I assume that might be the reason for you to read the template into a variable) try [output buffering](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

```
ob_start();
include 'some.template';
$out = ob_get_clean();
echo $out;
```

If you need to modify the template *before* having PHP process it, you will have to resort to [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). But I would advise you to be *very* careful with this for obvious security reasons and maybe-not-so-obvious performance reasons. If you just need some variables to be replaced, you should consider using a template engine instead or simple means like [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

Do not read the file into variable, instead do

```
 include 'some.template';
```

Comment: I have to edit template before inserting. include is wrong way.

Comment: Rewriting the PHP code in template? 

You really should rethink your design. If you could give more details about what exactly it is that you want to achieve, somebody can perhaps offer a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to edit the script before using it, the only way to do this practially is to use:

```
eval($string);
```

I'm sure I don't need to tell you not to do this with user input if you value security at all.

Comment: I'm sure that you do need to tell him that it is insecure, too many people are poor programmers to assume otherwise with a question like this.