# Activating a php file from another php file

Tags: php

I have abc.php and def.php files.For example I want to call def.php from abc.php .I found include() method but I don't want def.php to activate in background.I want browser to redraw the page according to html-php codes of def.php

Any ideas ?

Comment: you want to run it at background ?

Comment: [Executing php from another file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346708/executing-php-from-another-file)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php refer this

Answer (score 0):

You're probably talking about redirection.

You do that by issuing a location header.

Note that this has to run before any content is sent to the browser so it has to run before you show anything on the page. If you show some text and *then* send the location header, it will not work because headers must always come before content.

```
header('Location: def.php');
```

This will tell the browser to redirect to def.php.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for ur answer.However I have many contents I send to browser at abc.php before redirect =|

Comment: For that you will need JavaScript.

Look around on Google or ask another question on StackExchange with more detail, about opening a new page in a new window with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the content of `def.php`

Here is an example:

Page: `def.php`

```
<?PHP
  //do many things, but do not echo or print anything
  $output ="<div> all the codes</div>"; // collect the markup like this
  return $output; // return the output but still do not echo or print
?>
```

Now Page: `abc.php`

```
//do its own processing
$myDefPageOutput = include("def.php"); 
//This will only get the values of the return statement

//Now user $myDefPageOutput wherever you want and redraw the page
```

Comment: Thank you Starx.But the abc.php has many contents(strings,forms,links).I want to redraw the page with ONLY def.php markups depend on a condition which is at abc.php .I guess this code adds contents of def to below of abc contents.Am I right ?

Comment: @SedatKURT, Not really, it adds the contents of def.php to a variable and you can use where you like. Echo at top or bottom, its your choice

Comment: Hmmm but at the same time there are contents of abc on the page arent there ?